# Browser displays cached img instead of new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I'm using Croppic JQuery plugin for users to select/crop new images and replace old ones, for profile photo for instance. Everything works fine except after selecting/cropping and confirming new image browser will still show old image on page even if I reload page.

I'm not to familiar with caching but If this kind of problem is common one I need advice what to do here, because for know I must delete cache in order to see new image.

Answer (score 2):

I personally add a date to the image if needed

```
$("#image").prop("src",someUrl+"?"+new Date().getTime());
```